# Android - Future.get() makes UI freeze

Tags: java, android, user-interface, future, callable

I'm using a callable to run in a separate thread. But my UI get freezed when I call `futAdd.get()`

My code is

```
        Callable<Double[]> calAdd = new addCallable(values,values_2);
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 );
        Future<Double[]> futAdd = exec.submit( calAdd );

        try {
            Double[] ans = futAdd.get();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                 //
            }
```

Why the app freezes when it is running on a separate thread ?

Comment: can you show the error or any image?

Comment: It shows no error . When the button is clicked, the ui freezes.

Comment: I posted a code, check it

Comment: Don't perform blocking operations in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

The UI have been freezed, because it has too many work in thread, you can do the next

```
 val thread = Thread(Runnable {
                  Callable<Double[]> calAdd = new addCallable(values,values_2);
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 3 );
        Future<Double[]> futAdd = exec.submit( calAdd );

        try {
            Double[] ans = futAdd.get();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                 //
            }
            })
       thread.start()
```

// If you want to wait the result, you  can wait the result,

```
thread.join();
```

Comment: Now, it doesn't freeze but it doesn't do any other work described after futAdd.get().

Comment: you can wait the result, you only need the next: thread .join() or call the method in the thread